# Inject configuration into volume before Docker container starts

Tags: docker, configuration, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am looking for a way to create a Docker volume and put some data on it just before a specific container is started - which needs the configuration on startup.

I do not want to modify the container. I would like to use a vanilla container straight from the Docker Hub.

Any ideas?

### Update

I did not mention that all this has to be done in a compose file. If I would do it manually, I could wait for the configuration injecting container to finish.

Comment: Can you clarify what the specific issue is here?  The straight line approach here is to collate all the files you want into a host directory, and then mount that in your container with the `-v` flag.

Comment: THX! I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! Just create your volume beforehand, attach it to any container (A base OS like Ubuntu would work great), add your data, and you're good to go!

**Create the volume:**

```
docker volume create test_volume
```

**Attach it to an instance where you can add data:**

```
docker run --rm -it --name ubuntu_1 -v test_volume:/app ubuntu /bin/sh
```

**Add some data:**

Do this within the container; which you are in from the previous command.
    touch /app/my_file

**Exit the container:**

```
exit
```

**Attach the volume to your new container:**

Of course, replace `ubuntu` with your real image name.

```
docker run --rm -it --name ubuntu_2 -v test_volume:/app ubuntu /bin/sh
```

**Verify the data is there:**

```
~> ls app/
   my_file
```

Comment: @eventhorizon You won't be able to create and seed the volume in the composer file; but you could create and seed it beforehand and then in the compose file it can be attached. Just remember there may be a prefix on the volume name in the compose file.